# How to set class path for client of web service in build.xml

Tags: java, ant, classpath

HI,
I need to know how to set class path for the client tag 
 
under web service of build.xml in java.

I have to add the log4j.properties file to the client jar.

Thanks
Abhi

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about a build.xml in terms of ant.  Have a look at the [hello world with ant page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html).